# How to add a sunburst chart to a RDLC

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, visual-studio-2015, sunburst-diagram, ssrs-2016

I'm tasked with creating a report in a RLDC that contains a Sunburst chart which is one of the new charts that comes with SQL 2016.

However in Visual Studio 2015 the option to add that type of chart only appears if you add it in a RDL file that is part of a Report Project, and not a RDLC file in a c# project.   As this code is run on a web server rather than in than on the reporting server this presents a problem.

Is it possible to add a Sunburst chart to a RLDC?  If so how?

**RDL Select Chart Type**
[image: RDL Select Chart Type]

**RDLC Select Chart Type**
[image: RDLC Select Chart Type]

Manually adding the chart to the RDLC results in an error.  Sunburst is not a valid value
[image: Error: Sunburst is not a valid value]

Taking a RDL and renaming it to RDLC as per Dan Andrews suggestion results in
[image]

But that then errors out with

> The report definition has an invalid target namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition' which cannot be upgraded.

Comment: You could try renaming the RDL to RDLC, you can edit the XML to rip out all off the stuff (like connections) that RDLC's don't have.  This may help - or not: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252109(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @DanAndrews   That prompts to convert it to the latest RDLC format and then errors with "The report definition has an invalid target namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition' which cannot be upgraded. "

Comment: That sucks but worth a shot.  I hope someone else has an real answer.

Comment: @DanAndrews  Yes I am a bit.  But maybe only until they release the Report Viewer 2016 runtime to General Availability (currently in Release Candidate status).

Comment: Maybe this on GitHub? https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4348373 or https://bl.ocks.org/maybelinot/5552606564ef37b5de7e47ed2b7dc099

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RDLC-style reports are client-side reports that do not require SQL Server. The fact that sunbursts come with SQL Server 2016 is not relevant: the SQL Server version you have doesn't affect your RDLC reports.

You're looking to develop the kind of report that comes with Visual Studio ('local reports'), which will be at the level of RDLC file for Visual Studio 2015. It sounds like the Report Viewer 2016 control will come with functionality that may help.

Comment: Thought it was worth an answer rather than people trying to interpret the comments to your own question.

Comment: I heard later that they resolved this by upgrading to Visual Studio 2017 for development, then the sunburst is available.

Comment: Or is it more that Visual Studio 2017 includes the Report VIewer 2016 control?

Comment: Possibly. But I couldn't get it working in Visual Studio 2015 before I stopped working at the client.